# Multiline comments in sass after a declaration

Tags: css, sass, comments, node-sass

The SASS [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments) states:

> Sass supports standard multiline CSS comments with /* */, as well as single-line comments with //. The multiline comments are preserved in the CSS output where possible, while the single-line comments are removed.

That seems not to be always true.

```
/* what an ugly declaration */

body
  color: green
```

will be compiled to:

```
/* what an ugly declaration */

body {
  color: green; }
```

but if I put the comment after a property:

```
body
  color: green /* what an ugly color */
```

it will be removed:

```
body {
  color: green; }
```

Can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Seems to work as long as you terminate the line with a ";", although it does push it to the next line on compile http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/ddb21d2a5d3a75c2ff2211a68c21e81e

Comment: with the `;` it is not longer valid sass. Your example is written in scss

Answer (score 3):

Try adding /*! your comment code */ in your comment.

**Example:**

```
body{

color: green; /*! What an Ugly color */

}
```

This should help you.

Comment: this is neither sass, nor does the sass equivalent it work

Comment: I've found this solution when searching through the internet and it works for all of my sass code.

Comment: here's the link that i've found.
https://richwp.com/keep-comment-in-compressed-sass-scss/